# Cannot re-enter readline python

Tags: python

I'm making a basic Turtle game where you go go through a maze and get to the cheese, there's an issue with my win condition though, I know what the problem is, it's that the project is attempting to run an `input` when already expecting user input. I'm guessing that's because the `win()` function gets called multiple times before the user actually responds. I've tried multiple ways of fixing this to no avail. Here's my code:

```
import turtle
import datetime

won = False

turtle.setup(800, 590)

mouse_l = "mouse_l.gif"
mouse_r = "mouse_r.gif"
mouse_u = "mouse_u.gif"
mouse_d = "mouse_d.gif"
map = "map.gif"

turtle.setup(800, 590)
turtle.tracer(0, 0)
turtle.delay(0)

FRAME_TIME = 5 # in ms

wn = turtle.Screen()

wn.bgpic(map)
wn.register_shape(mouse_d)
wn.register_shape(mouse_r)
wn.register_shape(mouse_l)
wn.register_shape(mouse_u)

wn.tracer(0, delay=0)
wn.delay(0)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.penup()

player.shape(mouse_d)

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

keys = {
    "w": False,
    "s": False,
    "a": False,
    "d": False
}

def check_win():
    return player.ycor() < -230 and player.xcor() > 335

def win():
    global won
    global start_time
    
    print("You won!")
    won_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    final_time = won_time.replace(microsecond=0) - start_time.replace(microsecond=0)
    print(f"Your time was {final_time}")
    if input("Do you want to play again? y/n ").lower() == "y":
        won = False
        player.goto(-352, 195)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

def movement():
    global won
    
    if keys["w"]:
        player.seth(90)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["s"]:
        player.seth(270)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["a"]:
        player.seth(180)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["d"]:
        player.seth(0)
        player.fd(6)
    
    turtle.update()
    
    won = check_win()
    
    if won == True:
        won = "winning"
        return win()
    
    return wn.ontimer(movement, FRAME_TIME)

def c_keys(key, value):
    keys[key] = value

player.goto(-352, 195)
turtle.update()

movement()

wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("w", True), "w")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("w", False), "w")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("s", True), "s")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("s", False), "s")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("a", True), "a")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("a", False), "a")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("d", True), "d")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("d", False), "d")

wn.listen()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: Addressing Johnny Mopp's comment (Rework win check in `movement()`, tried a few ways, still getting the issue)

```
import turtle
import datetime

turtle.setup(800, 590)

prompting = False

mouse_l = "mouse_l.gif"
mouse_r = "mouse_r.gif"
mouse_u = "mouse_u.gif"
mouse_d = "mouse_d.gif"
map = "map.gif"

turtle.setup(800, 590)
turtle.tracer(0, 0)
turtle.delay(0)

FRAME_TIME = 5 # in ms

wn = turtle.Screen()

wn.bgpic(map)
wn.register_shape(mouse_d)
wn.register_shape(mouse_r)
wn.register_shape(mouse_l)
wn.register_shape(mouse_u)

wn.tracer(0, delay=0)
wn.delay(0)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.penup()

player.shape(mouse_d)

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

keys = {
    "w": False,
    "s": False,
    "a": False,
    "d": False
}

def won():
    return player.ycor() < -230 and player.xcor() > 335

def play_again():
    global start_time
    global prompting

    print("playing again", prompting)
    
    if prompting:
        return

    prompting = True
    
    print("You won!")
    won_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    final_time = won_time.replace(microsecond=0) - start_time.replace(microsecond=0)
    print(f"Your time was {final_time}")
    if input("Do you want to play again? y/n ").lower() == "y":
        player.goto(-352, 195)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

def movement(): 
    if keys["w"]:
        player.seth(90)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["s"]:
        player.seth(270)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["a"]:
        player.seth(180)
        player.fd(6)
    if keys["d"]:
        player.seth(0)
        player.fd(6)
    
    turtle.update()

    if won():
        return play_again()
    
    return wn.ontimer(movement, FRAME_TIME)

def c_keys(key, value):
    keys[key] = value

player.goto(-352, 195)
turtle.update()

movement()

wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("w", True), "w")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("w", False), "w")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("s", True), "s")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("s", False), "s")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("a", True), "a")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("a", False), "a")
wn.onkeypress(lambda: c_keys("d", True), "d")
wn.onkeyrelease(lambda: c_keys("d", False), "d")

wn.listen()
```

**EDIT 2**: Original error message

```
You won!
Your time was 0:00:03
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 80, in movement
    if won() and not play_again():
  File "main.py", line 57, in play_again
    if input("Do you want to play again? y/n ").lower() == "y":
RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline
```

Comment: If you choose "no" to "Do you want to play again?", then `win` stays `True`, and so the next time `wn.ontimer(movement, FRAME_TIME)` fires, the `if won == True:` condition will be `True`, and so `return win()` will be called again. So, you need to adjust your design to avoid that oversight.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes I know that's an issue, I want to at least _**be able to put in input**_ before I address that problem.

Comment: `input()` has no place in a GUI program - if the program is run by double-clicking, rather than from a terminal, then there won't even be any place for you to type anything in.  The `turtle` module has a `textinput()` function that would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm coding this on [repl.it](https://replit.com), there's a GUI tab as well as a console tab. If I used Turtle's `textinput()` it would still "flood" the input, and that's the problem I'm trying to solve right now.

Comment: I would get rid of the global `won` variable. Have the `win` function `return True` or `return False`. And then `if not win(): return`. (Changing the name of the function to something like `ask_play_again` might also be helpful.)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Check the edit, I tried your way with no global win variables, (prompting, won) and I still got the issue. The edit was my third attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def play_again():
    global start_time
   
    print("You won!")
    won_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    final_time = won_time.replace(microsecond=0) - start_time.replace(microsecond=0)
    print(f"Your time was {final_time}")

    if input("Do you want to play again? y/n ").lower() == "y":
        player.goto(-352, 195)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return True
    else:
        return False

def movement(): 
    # Other stuff removed for brevity
    #.......

    if won() and not play_again():
        return
    
    return wn.ontimer(movement, FRAME_TIME)
```

Comment: It prints the expected output, "You won", time, etc. but it still shows the original error. I think it's because the input itself in the `play_again()` function is getting called multiple times without a response. I've put the error I'm getting in edit #2 (dumb of me for not already).

Comment: I don't get that error. Must be something weird with the online IDE you are using.